# Updating GUI from multiple threads

Tags: c#

I’ve created a user control. In the control I have two methods – sending and receiving some data. Those methods also update the data grid located on the user control.

```
public void RunTX()
{    
    tx_run = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendCanFrames));
    if (!tx_run.IsAlive)
    {
        tx_run.IsBackground = true;
        tx_run.Start();
    }

}

public void RunRX()
{    
    rx_run = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadCanFrames));
    if (!rx_run.IsAlive)
    {
        rx_run.IsBackground = true;
        rx_run.Start();
    }
}

private void ReadCanFrames()
{
    ushort prev_time_stamp = 0;

    while (running)
    {
        if (CanDevice != null)
            CanDevice.Read(ref rx_can_msg, 1, ref read_cnt);

        if (read_cnt == 1)
        {
            read_cnt = 0;

            dataGridViewCanRx.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = rx_can_msg[0].Id.ToString("X");
            dataGridViewCanRx.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = rx_can_msg[0].Size.ToString();
            dataGridViewCanRx.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = BytesToString(rx_can_msg[0].Data);
             dataGridViewCanRx.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = (rx_can_msg[0].TimeStamp - prev_time_stamp).ToString();

            prev_time_stamp = rx_can_msg[0].TimeStamp;
        }

        prev_time_stamp = rx_can_msg[0].TimeStamp;
    }
}

private void SendCanFrames()
{
    if (tx_can_msg.Length == 0) return;

    VSCAN_MSG[] l_msgs = new VSCAN_MSG[2];

    while (running)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tx_can_msg.Length; i++)
        {
            if (can_messages[i].CountRun < can_messages[i].CountMax)
            {
                can_messages[i].TimeStamp1 = DateTime.Now;
                interval = can_messages[i].TimeStamp1 - can_messages[i].TimeStamp2;

                if (interval.TotalMilliseconds >= can_messages[i].Period)
                {
                    can_messages[i].TimeStamp2 = DateTime.Now;

                     l_msgs[0] = tx_can_msg[i];

                     //send CAN frame
                     CanDevice.Write(l_msgs, 1, ref written_cnt);
                     // send immediately 
                     CanDevice.Flush();

                     can_messages[i].CountRun++;

                    dataGridViewCanTx.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = can_messages[i].CountRun.ToString();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I put four user control instances on the main form and start all four controls.

```
private void buttonStartAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int can_channel;
    for (can_channel = 0; can_channel < 4; can_channel++)
    {
        if (started[can_channel] == false)
        {
            if (connected[can_channel] == true)
            {
                switch (can_channel)
                {
                    case 0:
                        mainform.userControlCan1.RunTX();
                        mainform.userControlCan1.RunRX();
                        started[can_channel] = true;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mainform.userControlCan2.RunTX();
                        mainform.userControlCan2.RunRX();
                        started[can_channel] = true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mainform.userControlCan3.RunTX();
                        mainform.userControlCan3.RunRX();
                        started[can_channel] = true;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mainform.userControlCan4.RunTX();
                        mainform.userControlCan4.RunRX();
                        started[can_channel] = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All is running, however the GUI freezing and data grids updated by jumps. Why?

Comment: 1) don't update UI from a _worker_ thread 2) don't let your UI thread enter an endless loop

Comment: Looks like you actually want to replace the loop with a WinForm/WPF Timer.

Comment: Actually I do nothing on main's form GUI. Controls update the grids in its threads. And without endless loop a thread runs once.

Comment: I think you need to call invoke on your Form to modify your GUI in your threads. `dataGridViewCanTx.Rows` is not executed on the maint thread and should break, isn't it ?

Comment: I tried to do   this.Invoke(
                         (MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                             dataGridViewCanRx.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = rx_can_msg[0].Id.ToString("X");
                             dataGridViewCanRx.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = rx_can_msg[0].Size.ToString();
                             dataGridViewCanRx.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = BytesToString(rx_can_msg[0].Data);
                             dataGridViewCanRx.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = (rx_can_msg[0].TimeStamp - prev_time_stamp).ToString();
                        });

Comment: The same result. It dosen't crush without invoke required because the grid is updated in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to look at two key points: Invoke and Application.DoEvents.

First one will help you to update your GUI in main thread instead of child threads. 
Have a look at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netframework-4.8

Application.DoEvents() method tells the system to do other waiting jobs without blocking in some loops. Otherwise updating GUI jobs are postponed and GUI is blocked. Here is the information about this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=netframework-4.8

```
private delegate void dlgUpdateRows(object[] rx_can_msg, int tID);

// Write actual type of rx_can_msg instead of object[] in method signature , second parameter should be your thread id if needed
private void UpdateRows(object[] rx_can_msg, int tID =0)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                object[] obj = new object[2];
                obj[0] = rx_can_msg;
                obj[1] = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                this.Invoke(new dlgUpdateRows(UpdateRows), obj);
            }
            else
            {
                //Here update your datagrid using rx_can_msg

            }
            //This row is important to avoid blocking
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do error handling
        }


    }
```

Comment: I see. So I should change the whole project drastically. The user control I created is a stand alone project - Windows Forms Control Library. It dosen't have Application object. It compiles as DLL and I add it in the Toolbox in the main project.

Comment: if you add a refference to System.Windows.Forms.dll(or add using System.Windows.Forms if already refferenced) you can use DoEvents() method.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I do have Application.DoEvents(); Thank you.